# If $|\psi(g)|=\psi(1)$ for $\varphi$ a faithful complex representation, why is $g\in Z(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If you have a faithful complex representation $\varphi\colon G\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ with character $\psi$, why does $|\psi(g)|=\psi(1)$  imply that $g$ is central?

I could show that if $\psi(g)=\psi(1)$, then $g\in\ker\varphi$. This follows since $\psi(g)$ is a sum of $n$ roots of unity, and $\psi(1)=n$, so this can only happen if all the roots are $1$. But $\varphi(g)$ is diagonalizable as its minimal polynomial divides $X^k-1$ where $k=\operatorname{ord}g$, so I get $\varphi(g)$ is similar to $I_n$, hence equal to $I_n$.

I was trying to show that it's possible to conclude that $\psi(gxg^{-1}x^{-1})=\psi(1)$, for all $x\in G$, since then $gxg^{-1}x^{-1}\in\ker\varphi=\{e\}$ since $\varphi$ is faithful, which would imply $g\in Z(G)$.

Comment: Doesn't this follow because the codomain of $\psi$ is $\Bbb C^\times$, which is abelian? So $\psi([g,x]) = [\psi(g),\psi(x)] = 1$.

Comment: Can you show that $|\psi(g)|=\psi(1)$ implies that $\varphi(g)$ has a single eigenvalue only? Because $\varphi(g)$ is diagonalizable this implies that $\varphi(g)$ is multiplication by a scalar. And that commutes with all the linear transformations. (sorry about forgetting the difference between *phi* and *varphi* initially)

Comment: @MikeMiller: $\psi$ is not a homomorphism, $\varphi$ is though.

Comment: Right, good point. Thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think so, the eigenvalues are all roots of unity, and, $\psi(1)=n=|\psi(g)|=|\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n|$. So $|\mu_1+\cdots+\mu_n|=n$, but this equality is achieved iff all the $\mu_i$ are the same.

Comment: And then $\varphi(gx)=\varphi(g)\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)\varphi(g)=\varphi(xg)$, so $gx=xg$ since $\varphi$ is faithful.

Comment: Correct, Kristina. You do need the diagonalizability of $\varphi(g)$ in some guise. This is known, when $G$ is finite.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the pointer.